# VueJs conditional wrapper inside v-for

Tags: loops, vue.js, conditional-statements, wrapper, v-for

Is there any way to make conditional wrapper in v-for loop ?

So I have something like this

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="(item in items)">
     <span v-if="item.date==newDate">Header</span>
     <div>{{item.text}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

But what I need is something like:
Not sure I can describe it in the code. but I need items to be in  wrapper whenever there is new  so like

```html
<section>
  <span> New v-if Span</span>
  <div> item 1</div>
  <div> item 2</div>
  <div> item 3</div>
</section>
<section>
  <span> New v-if Span</span>
  <div> item 4</div>
  <div> item 5</div>
  <div> item 6</div>
</section>
```

I guess I could refine my array, and check for groups before I have v-for, and do v-for in v-for
But maybe there is cooler way to do it in vue that I am not aware of ?

Comment: how does `items` look?

Comment: an array of objects

Comment: please share a snippet of that array

Comment: I am not really sure why that matters, it's very big  and long object, but it also could be `[{date: 2020-02-01, label: "item1"},{date: 2020-02-20, label: "item2}]` and question still applies

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this here,

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <section v-for="jump in Math.ceil(items.length/3)">
    <span>New v-if Span</span>
    <div v-for="item in items.slice(3*(jump-1), 3*(jump-1)+3)">item {{item}}</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah but that basically means I will have to know first how many groups and items in the group I have first. But looks like having 2x v-for loops is the only option

Comment: Yes, you will have to use 2 loops for this HTML structure (1 for groups, another for each group items). Also you don't have to know how many groups, you only need to know how many items in each group.